# Compiler thinks an int is a string. What is happening?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am trying to use this selection sorting algorithm to sort the contents of an array. However the compiler I am using (codeblocks) is giving me an error stating "cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}' to 'int' in assignment|." This is in reference to the line reading `minvalue = wordarray[startscan];` Both minvalue and startscan are ints and wordarray is an array. Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string wordarray [1024];
int main()
{
    int wordcount = 0;
    string filename;
    cout << "Please enter the name and location of your file." << endl;
    cin >> filename;
    ifstream testfile;
    testfile.open (filename.c_str());
    for (int i=0; i < 1024; ++i)
    {
        testfile >> wordarray[i];
        cout << wordarray[i] << endl;
    }
    testfile.close();
}
void arraysort (int size)
    {
        int startscan, minindex;
        int minvalue;
        for (startscan = 0; startscan < (size - 1); startscan++)
        {
        minindex = startscan;
        minvalue = wordarray[startscan]; //here
            for (int index = startscan + 1; index < size; index ++)
            {
                if (wordarray[index] < minvalue)
                {
                     minvalue = wordarray[index];
                     minindex = index;
                }
             }
             wordarray[minindex] = wordarray[startscan];
             wordarray[startscan] = minvalue;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Code::Blocks is not a compiler. And the error message is very literal. And the compiler does not think what you think it thinks.

Comment: So why is it that it believes that a value that has been declared as an int is a string?

Comment: I said, "And the compiler does not think what you think it thinks."

Comment: `>> 
So why is it that it believes that a value that has been declared as an int is a string?` It does not. It simply says that you cannot assign a `string` to an `int`

Comment: I think the answereres (inlcuding me) and you have a very different view on the situation and the involved data-types. This is not necessarily your fault and could keep you from finding any of the answers helpful. I offer to do some interactive helping in chat, if you catch me online, preferrably in a few hours in a chat, otherwise write a comment with "@Yunnosch" here to get my attention - in a say 6 hours.

Answer (score 4):

The error message describes your code in a clear way.

```
string wordarray [1024]; // strings
/**/
int minvalue; // int
/**/
minvalue = wordarray[startscan]; // attempt to assign a string to an int
```

You will have to reconsider what that line is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

`string wordarray [1024];` is an array of string's. Getting an element from an array of strings gives you a string:

```
auto word = wordarray[someInt]; //word is a string
```

In C++ there is no conversion from `std::string` to `int`.